# How to rewrite a function in a more compact and generalized way?

Tags: function-construction, expression-manipulation, meta-programming

Consider a function as

```
sum1:= {-1, 1} #[[1, 1]] + {0, 1} #[[1, 2]] + {1, 1} #[[1, 3]] +
{-1, 0} #[[2, 1]] + {0, 0} #[[2, 2]] + {1, 0} #[[2, 3]] +
{-1, -1} #[[3, 1]] + {0, -1} #[[3, 2]] + {1, -1} #[[3, 3]] &
```

I wish to write it in the following way,

```
sum2:= Module[{pos, val},
  pos = Table[{i, j}, {i, -1, 1, 1}, {j, -1, 1, 1}];
  val = Map[Table[#[[i, j]], {i, 1, 3, 1}, {j, 1, 3, 1}] &];
  pos val];
```

However, it's not giving me the desired output as

> {-1, 1} #1[[1, 1]] + {0, 1} #1[[1, 2]] + {1, 1} #1[[1, 3]] + {-1, 
>       0} #1[[2, 1]] + {0, 0} #1[[2, 2]] + {1, 0} #1[[2, 
>       3]] + {-1, -1} #1[[3, 1]] + {0, -1} #1[[3, 2]] + {1, -1} #1[[3, 
>       3]] &

How can I modify `sum2` to get the desired result?

Comment: Do you want to generate the function for later use or to write `sum1` procedure in a more generalized way? Close but not the same so I'm asking.

Comment: @Kuba I want both. Using `#` I want it to be used for a later purpose. In addition, I want to generalize it to be applied on 3D matrix as well.

Comment: What I meant is, do you want `sum2` to return `(...)&` so a `Function[...]` or do you want  `sum2[input]` to return whatever `(...)& @ input` would return. Very similar but different, see Alan's answer, he does not create an intermediate function but works directly with input (`mat33`).

Comment: @Kuba I want the first one you've mentioned.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 2):

We can use dummy `foo/bar` symbols instead of `Part` and `List` to prevent missing part error and an automatic threading for `{a,b} c`.

```
sum2 = Module[{pos, val, bar, foo}
, pos = Catenate @ Transpose @ Table[foo[i, j], {i, -1, 1}, {j, 1, -1, -1}]
; val = Catenate@Table[bar[#, i, j], {i, 3}, {j, 3}]
; Function[Evaluate[pos.val]] /. {foo -> List, bar -> Part}
]
```

> ```
> #1[[3, 1]] {-1, -1} + #1[[2, 1]] {-1, 0} + #1[[1, 1]] {-1, 1} + #1[[3,
>  2]] {0, -1} + #1[[2, 2]] {0, 0} + #1[[1, 2]] {0, 1} + #1[[3, 
> 3]] {1, -1} + #1[[2, 3]] {1, 0} + #1[[1, 3]] {1, 1} &
> ```

Comment: Another way to write `pos.val` is `Tr@(Array[part, {3, 3}].Array[list, {3, 3}, {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}])` which maybe useful for the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum3[mat33_?MatrixQ] := With[{
   pos = Reverse /@ Tuples[{-Range[-1, 1], Range[-1, 1]}],
   val = Extract[mat33, Tuples[Range[3], 2]]
   },
  Total[pos*val]
  ]
```

Or, letting `mA` be your 3-by-3 matrix, you could just `Total[mA*Outer[{#2, #1} &, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}], 2]`.

Comment: What is `mA` in the second part?

Comment: @Majis It's your 3 x 3 matrix.